# SUDS SOAP "dependancies suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found" Error

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine, soap, suds

I'm using [SUDS](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation) WSDL(SOAP) web services at GAE python.

& trying to consume this **46.51.221.138/PBExternalServices/v1/soap?wsdl**.

Here is **Py code**:

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client(url) 
print client
```

But its throwing some error at **console** as,

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soap.py", line 14, in <module>
    client = Client(url)
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 112, in __init__
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\reader.py", line 152, in open
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\wsdl.py", line 159, in __init__
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\wsdl.py", line 220, in build_schema
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\xsd\schema.py", line 95, in load
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\xsd\schema.py", line 323, in dereference
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\xsd\sxbasic.py", line 469, in dependencies
    suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(GetAccountBalanceFaultResponse, http://www.
    payback.net/lmsglobal/xsd/v1/types, )'
```

**NOTE:** I read some where that need to use `suds.xsd.doctor` because this WSDL seems broken in different way, but unfortunately i don't know how to use this `suds.xsd.doctor` here in this.

So any one of us had this issue before & got sorted out?, then please suggest proper solution to get resolve the same.

Warm Regrads,

Niks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
from suds.client import Client
wsdl_url = 'http://46.51.221.138/PBExternalServices/v1/soap?wsdl'
client = Client(wsdl_url, autoblend=True)
```